# eclipse Installation error (java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file)

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, eclipse-installer

I am trying to install eclipse IDE (Java for developers) , but facing the below error during the installation.

iam installing the eclipse on Ubuntu 18.4.

below is the java information of my pc.

> openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
>   10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)

```
2019-10-14 23:03:21] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2019-09/201909181001 in 0.692s
[2019-10-14 23:03:21] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2019-10-14 23:03:21] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:548)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:758)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3824)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3752)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3733)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3626)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1305)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1167)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1112)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=_home_pixel_eclipse_java-2019-09_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.util.zip.ZipException: Exception in opening zip file: /home/pixel/.p2/pool/plugins/com.google.guava_27.1.0.v20190517-1946.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3824)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3733)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1167)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1112)
  Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.zerror(ZipFile.java:1527)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.findEND(ZipFile.java:1341)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.initCEN(ZipFile.java:1435)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1266)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1229)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:727)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:845)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:175)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3824)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3752)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3733)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3626)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$32(SimpleVariablePage.java:1167
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you had a bad file transfer for `/home/pixel/.p2/pool/plugins/com.google.guava_27.1.0.v20190517-1946.jar` . Update to a properly supported JDK version (11 or newer) and retry it.